# Error in Angular JS shows the preview as {{dish.comment}} in browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to do an assignment on angular . It was working fine , then suddenly in the brackets preview , i am seeing {{dish.comment}} . I am a newbie. Everything seems to be fine in the file though.Below is the HTML file

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="tab-content">


            <li class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                     ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                     <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                     <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span> </h2>
                    <p ng-show="showDetails">{{dish.description}}</p>
                    </div>

                   </li>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

Below is the App.js file

```
angular.module('confusionApp', [])
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    }])
```

And i have included ng-app="confusionApp" in the HTM tag and also included
scripts/app.js at the bottom

Comment: Just a suggestion: use your browser console... (on `F12` key...)

Comment: Could you provide plunker, or at least log of console?

Comment: app.js:162 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment -- on the console . @MarcoS

Comment: You should show line 162 in app.js... Or, better, provide a plunker... :-)

Comment: Thank you @MarcoS for lettimg me know how to find an issue. I cleared the issue on line 62. Thank you!!

Comment: @KRISHNA: Happy to hear you solved yourself... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('confusionApp', [])
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row-content" ng-app="confusionApp" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="tab-content">
            <li class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                     ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                     <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                     <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span> </h2>
                     <span>{{dish.comments[0].comment}}</span>
                    <p ng-show="showDetails">{{dish.description}}</p>
                    </div>

                   </li>
                   
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--<div ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments">
                    <p>
                      {{comment.comment}}
                    </p>
                  </div> -->
                  </div>
```

See comments is array of object so you need to iterate or you can get specific value by using `{{dish.comments[0].comment}}`

I hope it will solve your problem